# mysql SELECT * FROM and SELECT TIME_FORMAT in 1 query

Tags: php, mysql

I encountered a problem implementing mysql `SELECT * FROM` and `SELECT TIME_FORMAT` in one query. This is my query

```
$result = $db->query(
    "SELECT
        *
    FROM
        form_data
    ORDER BY
        id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) -
```

UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LastUpdated)),'%Hh %im')
        FROM
           form_data
        ORDER BY
           id"
    );

The code that i tried to use this query with:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];

    echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["studentid"].'</td> 
            <td><b><a href="requestdetails.php?id=' . $id . '">' . $title . '</a></b></td>
            <td>'.$row["category"].'</td>  
            <td>'.$row["status"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["LastUpdated"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LastUpdated)),'%Hh %im')"].'</td>
          </tr>';
  }
```

Can I know where did I made a mistake ?

Comment: Are you sure the original query works? UNION all needs en equal number of columns between the queries unioned. And why do you even need a union when you select from the same table.

Comment: I don't think this `$row["TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LastUpdated)),'%Hh %im')"]` looks right

Comment: `SELECT * FROM form_data, TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LastUpdated)),'%Hh %im') as tt  FROM form_data ORDER BY id` ?

Comment: Also UNION ALL isn't necessary. You are only selecting from one table, yes?

Comment: Can I know how to implement them together because this is my first time dealing with SELECT TIME_FORMAT, sorry for the wrong implementation

Comment: Yes it is from one table

Comment: If you want the modified LastUpdated for each user, then just add it to the select. Either specify all of the columns, or use `SELECT *,TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(U....`. By the way, you can alias the column name with the `AS` keyword so you can get it out of the results easier.

Comment: thx aynber and splash58 for the help, i managed to solve the problem and finally get the implementation methods correct

Answer (score 0):

the corrected query is:

```
SELECT *,
  TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LastUpdated)),'%Hh %im') AS tt
FROM form_data
ORDER BY id
```